# Roots in different algebraic closure have the same multiplicative relations

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be an irreducible monic polynomial, with $f(0) \ne 0$, and $p$ a prime number. Also, let $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p$ be all the roots of $f$ taken in the algebraic closure of the $p$-adic numbers, and let $b_1, \ldots, b_n \in \mathbb{C}$ be all the roots of $f$ taken in the complex numbers.
Finally, let $A$ be the multiplicative group generated by $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ and let $B$ be the multiplicative group generated by $b_1, \ldots, b_n$.

Is is true that there is a group isomorphism $\phi : A \to B$, such that $\phi(a_i) = b_{\pi(i)}$ for all $i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$ and some permutation $\pi$ of $\{1, \ldots, n\}$? If so, how can I construct it?

This question is related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1974785) other.

Although Mariano Suárez-Álvarez answer is good. I would like to make work mercio's idea.

Please, let me know is this is fine:

Inside $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ we can construct an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ as 
$$\overline{\mathbb{Q}}^{\;\prime} = \{a \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}_p} : f(a) = 0 \text{ for some } f \in \mathbb{Q}[x]\}$$ (Exactly how $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ is usually constructed inside $\mathbb{C}$).
Now $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}^{\;\prime}$ while $b_1, \ldots, b_n \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. But the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ is unique up to isomorphism, so there exists an isomorphism $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}^{\; \prime} \to \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ that restricted to $A \to B$ does the job. Right?

Thank you again.

Comment: can't you just pick $f(x) = (x-1)(x+1)$ to get a counter-example ?

Comment: @mercio I meant irreducible polynomial in the question, sorry I fixed it.

Comment: anyway the roots are in $\overline {\Bbb Q}$ so it's not necessary to talk about $\Bbb C$ or $\overline {\Bbb Q_p}$

Comment: @mercio, notice that if you do restrict to $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ my argument stops working, as it is not true that all countable algebraically closed fields of characteristiz zero are isomorphic. So while it is not necessary to use $\mathbb C$, it is useful!

Comment: @mercio I have a problem with working in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ as you say. The hypotheses are $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ and $b_1, \ldots, b_n \in \mathbb{C}$ and I can change them: I agree that both $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ contain a subfield isomorphic to $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, but I do not see any relation between this two subfields in order to get $\phi$.

Comment: I meant "I can't change them"

Answer (score 3):

The field $\overline{\mathbb Q}_p$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb C$, so yes. Fix any isomorphism $\overline{\mathbb Q}_p\to\mathbb C$, show that it restricts to a bijection $A\to B$, and voilà.

(See [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23264/are-c-and-barq-p-isomorphic), for example, for a discussion of the isomorphism.)

Comment: I would had never expected an answer of this kind. Really interesting, thanks. I found that the existence of an isomorphism between $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p$ and $\mathbb{C}$ follows from a theorem of Steinitz.

Comment: I also tried mercio's idea in my question, if you can check it I'll be grateful!